# I don't understand "there is/isn't no" and "is/isn't there" kind of phrases

Tags: grammar

A friend asked me if I thought this phrase was correct:

> "It seems there isn't a free cam, is there?"

I replied I think it should be:

> "It looks like there isn't a free cam, isn't there?"

He objected that the second "isn't" should not be negative, like this:

> "It looks like there isn't a free cam, is there?"

I thought "oh yeah, that's right" and said that maybe this costruction was better:

> "There is no free cam, isn't there?"

Should it be

> "There is no free cam, is there?"

instead? I thought I knew this but I'm doubting it now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to form this tag question?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/155653/how-to-form-this-tag-question) As the OP there points out: *We always use a positive tag question after a negative sentence. We use a negative tag question after a positive sentence.*

Comment: And there are lots of ways to make a negative sentence: _Nobody showed up, did they? There was nobody there, was there? I don't believe he came, did he?_ All of them call for an affirmative tag. [Tag questions are not as simple as you might have been led to believe](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/tags.pdf).

Comment: This has been discussed many times here. Please see the duplicate ans repost any new question that might confuse you about it.

Comment: @medica, I with there was downvote for comments. Would gladly applied it to medica's one

Answer (score 1):

Each of these sentences -

"It looks like there isn't a free cam, is there?"

and

"There is no free cam, is there?"
are grammatically correct.

You don't follow one negation with another. What you are trying to do here is make a statement and then try to look for someone to negate that statement. Hence the single negation policy.

Answer (score 0):

Both wrong. Apparently, there aren't any free cams. Or,

No free cams.

NEVER use "is no." Think logically.