# What should we fiil in in the blank?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, pronouns

Everyone was interested in the news,________________?

Is the answer "wasn't he"? If not, what should it be?

Other choices include:
-was he
-were they
-weren't they

Comment: Everyone implies a group (i.e. more than one) so the pronoun has to be plural.

Comment: There's no 'satisfactory' answer here. What people do is use 'weren't they'. Purists might recast to 'All the people ....'

Comment: *Everyone **was** there, **weren't** they?, Everyone **is** here, **aren't** they?* Everyone is syntactically singular, but semantically lural.

Comment: Specifically the duplicates of that question and this for whether it should be negative: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/155653/191178